# Allow a div to scroll for x amount but then stop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, scroll

I have a div that is 700px high, under that div is a 200px picture. I want to allow scrolling for the first 700px but then no more. So on smaller vertical resolutions users can scroll to see the first 700px but then the rest is "cut off".

On the other hand users on large vertical resolutions will see the 700px div and the picture all with no scrollbar.

How can it be done?

Comment: @gdoron I've tried lots of things with css (Here is the basic layout: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/CFuNB/10/) I was trying to use the overflow property to do it. I've also looked at the clip and max-height property) and I don't know much about jquery but have a feeling I might need to use it for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use css media queries to use different css on different window size.

```
@media all and (min-width: 350px) and (min-height: 950px) {
    // css for a window size of 250px height and 750px width or higher
}
```

So you want to do something like this?

```
.content {
    height: 700px;
    width: 300px;
}

.main {
    height: 700px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}

.pic {
    display: none;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
}

@media all and (min-height: 950px) {
    .content {
        height: 900px;
    }
    .pic {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Comment: close, ideally I would like the picture to be constantly there but depending on your resolution you see different amount of it. At a 710px vertical resolution you'd see the top div and 10px of the image but no scrollbar. (The picture unfortunately cannot be apart of the background)

Comment: Well actually I got it working, I'm not 100% sure why but
`@media all and (min-height: 710px) {

html {
overflow-y:hidden;
}

.apple {
display: block;
}
`